# Automate gcloud components update

Tags: gcloud

How can I update the `gcloud components` programmatically within a shell script?

Calling `gcloud components update` requires an user entry, e.g.:

```
$ gcloud components update

The following components will be installed:
--------------------------------------------
| kubectl (Linux, x86_64) | 1.0.1 | 4.5 MB |
--------------------------------------------

For the latest release notes, please visit:
  https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/release/RELEASE_NOTES
Do you want to continue (Y/n)?
```

I can't find an argument for `gcloud` to enforce the update.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You're looking for the `--quiet` flag.

From `gcloud --help`:

```
 --quiet, -q
    Disable all interactive prompts when running gcloud commands. If input
    is required, defaults will be used, or an error will be raised.
```

This is generally a flag you'll want for non-interactive contexts.

You may also set the `CLOUDSDK_CORE_DISABLE_PROMPTS` environment variable to a non-empty value:

```
export CLOUDSDK_CORE_DISABLE_PROMPTS=1
gcloud components update # This works for all gcloud commands
```

Comment: I forgot I previously had the env variable set so I wasn't sure what was going on when I was just rolling the scripts solo.  Thanks for the help :D

Comment: By default, using `--quiet` doesn't work: `ERROR: Cannot use bundled Python installation to update Cloud SDK in non-interactive mode. Please run again in interactive mode.` and some workaround about `gcloud components copy-bundled-python`.

Comment: To make this work, for some reason I had to put the --quiet flag at the beginning of the command.  Otherwise I got the same error.  Here's an abbreviated version of the command that worked: `gcloud --quiet beta firebase test android run --timeout 30m --use-orchestrator --app app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk --test app/build/outputs/apk/androidTest/debug/app-debug-androidTest.apk`.  Note I'm running in gitlab CI.

Comment: What if i want to change the default to No because seems default is yes, this for me is a temporal action

Comment: Thanks @MichaelOsofsky. I had the exact same problem with `beta`. Once I put `--quiet` at the beginning (e.g. `gcloud --quiet beta functions deploy`), it worked!

Comment: For me --quiet was not working with gcloud beta composer. So went with export CLOUDSDK_CORE_DISABLE_PROMPTS=1

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter this problem while running a gcloud command on a Continuous Integration (CI) server, one thing you can try is run with a Docker image that already contains the components you need.  Thus you can avoid having to update gcloud components.

For example, if you're trying to run `gcloud beta firebase test android run`, you could use the `image: google/cloud-sdk:latest` because at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sdk-docker it shows :latest contains gcloud Beta Commands.

I tested this on Gitlab hosted CI (.gitlab-ci.yml) and it worked.